# Custom C-arrow cursor movement

Tags: key-bindings, commands, interactive, shift-selection

I was not satisfied with the behavior of standard `C-arrow` and `C-S-arrow`, so I wrote this functions to replace standard ones.

```
(setq separators-regexp "[\-'\"();:,.\\/?!@#%&*+=]")

(defun forward-to-separator()
    "Move to the next separator like in the every NORMAL editor"
    (interactive)
    (let ((my-pos (re-search-forward separators-regexp)))
        (goto-char my-pos)))

(defun backward-to-separator()
    "Move to the previous separator like in the every NORMAL editor"
    (interactive)
    (let ((my-pos (re-search-backward separators-regexp)))
        (goto-char my-pos)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<right>") 'forward-to-separator)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<left>") 'backward-to-separator)
```

But now I am facing a problem with shift selection: it actually just not working at all.
So my question is: how can I select text using my new functions and shift key(`C-S-arrow`)?

My final code is here:  https://gist.github.com/FirstTimeInForever/8303ac1918c81365991d7acf7a926bd8
I added `C-<backspace>` support and changed my regex. Now I can move cursor like in sublime text!

Comment: Why not just set a mark (`C-<SPC>`) from where you want to select and proceed to use your cursor movement functions?

Comment: I know I can set a mark, but selecting text with shift is more comfortable for me.

Comment: Excelent, do you know how to implement jumps over black characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`(interactive "^")`** instead of `(interactive)`.

`C-h f interactive` tells you, way down near the bottom:

> If the string begins with **`^`** and `shift-select-mode` is non-nil,
>    Emacs first calls the function `handle-shift-selection`.

In your case, the commands do not take an argument.  But you can still use a string argument to `interactive`, in this case `"^"`, to make the command respect shift selection.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded your code so cursor navigation is now behaving a lot better then default setting in Atom editor. Mainly I added skipping blank spaces in file.

I highly recommend binding those to `C-<right>` and `C-<left>` because in CUA mode, `C-S-<right>` and `C-S-<left>` is automatically binded to skipped text selection so you can easily copy/remove as in other editors.

```
(require 'cl-macs)

(setq custom/separators-regexp
      "\\([]['\"(){};:,.\\/?!@#%&*+=^[:space:]\n-]\\|\\s_\\|\\`\\|‌​‌​\\'\\)")

(defun custom/position-normalize-forward (saved-pos my-pos)
  (if (>= (- my-pos saved-pos) 2)
      (progn
        (goto-char my-pos)
        (if (not (eq my-pos (point-max)))
            (progn
              (custom/backward-symbol))))
    (progn
      (goto-char my-pos))))

(defun custom/forward-symbol ()
  (interactive "^")
  (block custom/forward-symbol
    (let* ((saved-pos (point))
           (my-pos (re-search-forward custom/separators-regexp))
           (my-pos2 (custom/find-blank-space t saved-pos)))
      (if (> my-pos2 my-pos)
          (progn
            (goto-char (- my-pos2 1))
            (return-from custom/forward-symbol)))
      (if (eq my-pos 1)
          (progn
            (goto-char (+ my-pos 1))
            (setf my-pos (re-search-forward custom/separators-regexp))
            (custom/position-normalize-forward saved-pos my-pos))
        (custom/position-normalize-forward saved-pos my-pos)))))


(defun custom/position-normalize-backward (saved-pos my-pos)
  (if (>= (- saved-pos my-pos) 2)
      (progn
        (goto-char my-pos)
        (if (not (eq my-pos 1))
            (progn
              (custom/forward-symbol))))
    (progn
      (goto-char my-pos))))

(defun custom/backward-symbol ()
  (interactive "^")
  (block custom/backward-symbol
    (let* ((saved-pos (point))
           (my-pos (re-search-backward custom/separators-regexp))
           (my-pos2 (custom/find-blank-space nil saved-pos)))
      (if (< my-pos2 my-pos)
          (progn
            (goto-char (+ my-pos2 1))
            (return-from custom/backward-symbol)))
      (if (eq my-pos (point-max))
          (progn
            (goto-char (- my-pos 1))
            (setf my-pos (re-search-backward custom/separators-regexp))
            (custom/position-normalize-backward saved-pos my-pos))
        (custom/position-normalize-backward saved-pos my-pos)))))

(defun custom/find-blank-space (go-forward starting-pos)
  (let ((starting-char (string (char-after starting-pos)))
        (skipped-count 0)
        (increment (if go-forward 1 -1))
        (should-loop t))
    (if (or (equal starting-char " ")
            (equal starting-char "\t")
            (equal starting-char "\n"))
        (progn
          (while should-loop
            (if (or (equal (string (char-after (+ saved-pos skipped-count))) " ")
                    (equal (string (char-after (+ saved-pos skipped-count))) "\t")
                    (equal (string (char-after (+ saved-pos skipped-count))) "\n"))
                (setq skipped-count (+ skipped-count increment))
              (setq should-loop nil)))
          (+ starting-pos skipped-count))
      starting-pos)))
```

Hope it will help.