# how to make emacs think semicolon and brackets are words?

Tags: syntax-table, words

i've came on emacs from Sublime Text, and there `;[]{}().,` etc are counts as word, and when you move in your document with Ctrl+Arrow you never skip these characters. I want make emacs recognize all these characters as separate word. How do i? Is there easy way to do this?

Comment: You may wish to try `(forward-symbol 1)` instead of `forward-word`; and, `(forward-symbol -1)` instead of `backward-word`.  Doc-string of `forward-symbol`:  "*Move point to the next position that is the end of a symbol.
A symbol is any sequence of characters that are in either the
word constituent or symbol constituent syntax class.
With prefix argument ARG, do it ARG times if positive, or move
backwards ARG times if negative.*"  Alternatively, you may wish to consider writing up your own custom movement function that mimics other popular text editors and/or word processors.

Comment: forward-symbol works even worse

Answer (score 1):

If every character mentioned should compose a single word, try something like this:

```
(defvar pseudowords (list ?\; ?\[ ?\] ?{ ?} ?\( ?\) ?. ?,))

(defun ar-forward-extended-words ()
  (interactive)
  (or (when (member (char-after) pseudowords)
    (progn (forward-char 1)
           t))
      (when
      ;; regexp below might require some edits
      (< 0 (skip-chars-forward "^[a-z];[]{}\\().,"))
    (progn
      (forward-char 1)
      t))
      (forward-word 1)))
```

If it's just to extend which character belongs to a specific syntax, this controlled by syntax-tables. There is a function to change the contents of this table.
For example if in python-mode the underscore should get word-syntax, write

`(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" python-mode-syntax-table)`

The char behind the question mark will get the syntax according  to symbol in next slot, word-syntax here represented by string "w".

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, they don't *exactly* want these punctuation characters to be word-constituent, because they want them to be *separate words* which would mean that `foo()` was three words.

Comment: phils is right.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create own function. [Here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26417/custom-c-arrow-cursor-movement) you can have implementation that works.

Comment: So it's about navigating paired delimiteds?